# How do I get table rows to size correctly in all browsers when using a rowspan?

Tags: html, css, html-table, cross-browser

I'm trying to write some simple HTML/CSS using a rowspan. I'm pretty sure the code is correct, but it doesn't give the result I expect. Also, each browser gives a *different* result. I thought HTML was supposed to be a standard?

Some simplified code can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pyzezrev/1/).

This is what I'm trying to achieve. A three-row table, height dependent on its contents, with a 2px middle row, and the other two rows equally sharing the remaining space:

[image: Intended result]

Here's what I get in Chrome:

[image: Chrome result]

Here's what I get in Safari:

[image: Safari result]

And here's what I get in Firefox:

[image: Firefox result]

I've tried using divs instead of tables (`display: table-cell` etc), and it only caused more problems, such as the result being misaligned with other elements on the page.

**My question is this: How can I achieve my intended result, consistently, across all browsers?**

I would rather not use Javascript to solve this.

To avoid the XY problem, here are some screenshots of the actual effect I'm after (working in Chrome):

[image: Actual intended result]

Here's it all going to hell in Safari:

[image: Safari nonsense]

And here's it screwing up in Firefox:

[image: Firefox nonsense]

Comment: you need to fake a fieldset visual(redundant question in the last 15 years). It can be done from almost any display. from display:table-caption to inline-block ... ommitting a few, such as list-item or inline. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bowOGb margin, line-height, vertical-align,display,shadow,background, ... can be used (depends on situation, imagination and HTML structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd solve this problem using divs instead of tables. Using the position property of both the parent element and child element along with the transform property on the child element to allow it to sit in front of the bordered parent element. This would be cross browser compatible. Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title"><span>Title</span></h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.title span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2em 0.7em; 
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a standard in as much as browsers follow it, which they don't. It's specially tricky to control tables with `col` and `row spans`. I would try using table-less and `flex` layout, as in the following simplified example.

```css
body {
  background-color:white;
}

.outer {
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding:16px;
  position:relative;
  margin-top:20px;
}

.title {
  margin:-24px auto 0px auto;
  width:60px;
  background-color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

.icon-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.icon {
  border:1px dashed grey;
  height:50px;
  margin:8px;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="title">TITLE</div>
  <div class="icon-container">
    <div class="icon">ICON 1</div>
    <div class="icon">ICON 2</div>
    <div class="icon">ICON 3</div>
    <div class="icon">ICON 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will need to investigate flex layout.